# CSS Background crossfading issue

Tags: css, image, webkit, css-transitions, transition

i'm experiencing an issue with my background crossfading not working AT ALL.
Maybe someone would be able to tell me what have i done wrong? :)
Here's the script:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="backgroundchange">
        <div class="bgimg" id="bg1">
            <div class="title centerV">
                <div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1>Malarstwo</h1>
                        <p>Beaty Domanskiej</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bgimg" id="bg2">
            <div class="title centerV">
                <div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1>Malarstwo</h1>
                        <p>Beaty Domanskiej</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="bgimg" id="bg3">
            <div class="title centerV">
                <div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1>Malarstwo</h1>
                        <p>Beaty Domanskiej</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bgimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#bg1 {
    background-image: url("../img/gallery/slonecz.jpg");
}

#bg2 {
    background-image: url("../img/gallery/motyl.jpg");
}

#bg3 {
    background-image: url("../img/gallery/slonecz.jpg");
}

@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    17% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    25% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    92% {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation-delay: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation-delay: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
}

#backgroundchange div:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation-delay: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
}

#backgroundchange div {
    animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
}
```

As a result, i can see the first background set, but it never crossfades into the next one.

Comment: Where's your JavaScript logic and control flow to handle the functionality? HTML and CSS alone are not enough for true dynamic possibilities of HTML5/CSS/JavaScript. EDIT in case my subtlety wasn't clear enough: your HTML / CSS combination lacks the third crucial piece to make it dynamic HTML5: JavaScript!

Comment: Jerusalem, i know JS actually makes it even easier for this purpose, still i need to do this in CSS because of the style will be applied to further elements too. Thanks for your comment/answer tho!

Comment: The answer of Banzay actually make it work great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want smth like this?

Here is a code that works on my laptop:

## CSS:

```css
.bgimg {
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    box-shadow: inset 4px 1px 77px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.78);
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("../img/gallery/slonecz.jpg");
    animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-duration: 8s;
    -webkit-animation-name: backgroundchangeFadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
}

@keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut {
    0% {
       background-image: url("../img/gallery/slonecz.jpg");
    }
    50% {
       background-image: url("../img/gallery/motyl.jpg");
    }
    100% {
       background-image: url("../img/gallery/slonecz.jpg");
   }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<div class="bg">
    <div class="backgroundchange">
        <div class="bgimg" id="bg1">
            <div class="title centerV">
                <div>
                    <div class="text">
                        <h1>Malarstwo</h1>
                        <p>Beaty Domanskiej</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the front page actually looks like this: https://s29.postimg.org/abjplgptj/example.jpg   And i want to make the background image fade out into another with an infinite loop. When i run your code snippet it just blinks every few seconds so not sure whether it works, would try to implement it into my code in a sec

Comment: I've changed an answer. Look at that

Comment: woah, you are a coding racing car hahaha, i've been halfway making this when u posted that answer :P

Comment: You're welcome! :) don't forget to upvote and accept this answer :)

Comment: actually need more rep to upvote unfortunatelly, but since i accepted the answer it will most likely get upvoted by others, sincerely thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can't set an animation without setting a css @keyframe.

add the keyframes to your all animations here is an example below:

```
 @-webkit-keyframes backgroundchangeFadeInOut{
            0% {transform: translateY(-100%); opacity: 0;}
            80% {transform: translateY(40%);}
            100% {transform: translateY(0%); opacity: 1;}
        }
```

Comment: There are few keyframes set already, also implemented the one you provided and still no effect, wondering where have i made a mistake. Correct me if im wrong - i can put keyframes code ANYWHERE in my css file, it doesnt need to be right after the style it relates to?