# How do you add pictures over a previous background HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image

I want to add a set off three pictures at the bottom of a website i've been designing.  I have a previous background and I understand how the "z-index" command works but I do not know how to add css to the picture itself. Any answers would be great, thanks.

Comment: Is there any code of yours to start answer from ?

Comment: Please provide us with some code, whatever it is you have now with the website, background, and images you want to use. Please provide a working example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41522752/4206079

Answer (score -2):

You can a class or id to the image and add css rules to the respective id or class.